# Using regex to match beginning and end of string [Java]

Tags: java, regex, string-matching

I have a list of files in a folder:

```
maze1.in.txt
maze2.in.txt
maze3.in.txt
```

I've used substring to remove the .txt extensions.
How do I use regex to match the front and the back of the file name?
I need it to match "maze" at the front and ".in" at the back, and the middle must be a digit (can be single or double digit).

I've tried the following

```
if (name.matches("name\\din")) {
    //dosomething
}
```

It doesn't match anything. What is the correct regex expression to use?

Comment: This might be useful when starting out with regular expressions http://www.debuggex.com/

Answer (score 13):

I'm a little confused what you are asking for in particular

```
    ^(maze[0-9]*\.in)$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

This will match  maze(any number).in

```
 ^(maze[0-9]*\.in)\.txt$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

this will match maze(any number).in.txt -- excludes the .txt NO NEED FOR USING SUB STRING!

[Edit live on Debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/r/S7knGXrh6zK6DmEt)

The think i would be wary about as of right now is the [capture groups](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html)... I'm not particularly sure what you are doing with this regex. However, I believe explaining capture groups could benefit you.

A capture group for instance is denoted by () this is basically store them in the pattern array and is a way to parse stuff.

example maze1.in.txt

So if you want to capture the entire line minus .txt i would use this `^(maze[0-9]*\.in\.txt)$`

However, if I wanted to capture things separately I would do this `^(maze)([0-9]*)(\.in)\.txt$` this will exclude .txt but include maze, the number, and .in IN separate indexes of the pattern array.

Comment: You need the `^`, or `$` if using `String.matches()`. It automatically tries to match the entire string (yeah this isn't documented).

Answer (score 2):

Your original solution doesn't work because string "name" is not in your text. It is "maze". 
You can try this

```
name.matches("maze\\d{1,2}\\.in")
```

d{1,2} is used to match a digit(can be single or double digit).

Answer (score 1):

You need regex anchors that tell the regex to

start at the beginning: `^`

and signal the end of the string: `$`

```
^maze[\d]{0,2}\.in$
```

or in Java:

```
name.matches("^maze[\\d]{0,2}\\.in$");
```

Also, your regex wasn't matching strings with a dot (`.`) which would not accept your examples given.  You need to add `\.` to the regex to accept dots because `.` is a special character.

Comment: Actually that isn't required for `String.matches()`. It automatically tries to match the whole string as if `^` and `$` were there.

Answer (score 0):

It is always good to think of what you are trying to do in english, before you create regular expressions.

You want to match a word `maze` followed by a digit, followed by a literal period `.` followed by another word.

```
word   `\w` matches a word character
digit  `\d` matches a single digit
period `\.` matches a literal period
word   `\w` matches a word character
```

putting it all together into a single string you get (keep in mind the double backslash for the Java escape and the pluses to repeat the previous match one or more times):

```
"\\w+\\d\\.\\w+"
```

The above is the generic case for *any* file name in the format `xxx1.yyy`, if you wanted to match `maze` and `in` specifically, you can just add those in as literal strings.

```
"maze\\d+\\.in"
```

example: http://ideone.com/rS7tw1

Answer (score 0):

```
name.matches("^maze[0-9]+\\.in\\.txt$")
```